# Expand rows by date range having start and end in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm working with a data set containing information on a phenomenon occurring during some time frames. I am given the start and end time of the event and its severity, as well as some other information. I would like to expand these frames over some larger time period by expanding the rows within set time periods and leaving the rest of the information as NaNs.

Data set example:

```
                         date_end         severity   category
     date_start           
2018-01-04 07:00:00  2018-01-04 10:00:00     12          1
2018-01-04 12:00:00  2018-01-04 13:00:00     44          2
```

What I want is:

```
                     severity   category
     date_start           
2018-01-04 07:00:00     12         1
2018-01-04 08:00:00     12         1
2018-01-04 09:00:00     12         1
2018-01-04 10:00:00     12         1
2018-01-04 11:00:00     nan       nan
2018-01-04 12:00:00     44         2
2018-01-04 13:00:00     44         2
2018-01-04 14:00:00     nan       nan
2018-01-04 15:00:00     nan       nan
```

What would be an efficient way of achieving such a result?

Comment: How did you determine the end of the date_start range?

Comment: It would be arbitrary, could work as:
`datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: Is the end_date on the first line should be 10:00  instead of 7:00 per the expected output? And the date_start on the second line should be 2018-01-04 instead of 2018-01-05?

Comment: yeah, good point, I made a mistake with formatting

Comment: and the second date_start is `2018-01-04 12:00:00` instead of `2018-01-05 12:00:00`

Comment: date start is early than end , please check the 2nd row

Comment: Thanks! edited it, it should look as intended now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are on pandas v0.25, use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['hour'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row.name, row['date_end'], freq='H'), axis=1)
df = df.explode('hour').reset_index() \
        .drop(columns=['date_start', 'date_end']) \
        .rename(columns={'hour': 'date_start'}) \
        .set_index('date_start')
```

For the rows with `nan`, you may reindex your dataframe.

```
# Report from Jan 4 - 5, 2018, from 7AM - 7PM
days = pd.date_range('2018-01-04', '2018-01-05')
hours = pd.to_timedelta(range(7, 20), unit='h')
tmp = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([days, hours], names=['Date', 'Hour']).to_frame()

s = tmp['Date'] + tmp['Hour']
df.reindex(s)
```

Comment: question about reindexing for doing so I used:
```date_range = pd.date_range(start=date_start, end=date_end, freq='H')
df.reindex(date_range, fill_value=np.NaN)```
before establishing date_start as min of date_start, and date_end as arbitrary values
which solution would you say works better

Comment: Your solution reports on all 24 hours of the day. My answer only reports between 7AM - 7PM. Both work just as well, but for slightly different purposes.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Also sorry for the formatting, I'm still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to reindex the datafame using pd.date_range, the use ffill and mask the values where the index is greater than date_end.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df['date_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_end'])

df1 = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), '2018-01-04 15:00:00', freq='H'))

df1 = df1.ffill()

df1.loc[(df1.index - df1['date_end']) > pd.Timedelta(days=0)] = np.nan

df_out = df1.drop('date_end', axis=1)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                     severity  category
2018-01-04 07:00:00      12.0       1.0
2018-01-04 08:00:00      12.0       1.0
2018-01-04 09:00:00      12.0       1.0
2018-01-04 10:00:00      12.0       1.0
2018-01-04 11:00:00       NaN       NaN
2018-01-04 12:00:00      44.0       2.0
2018-01-04 13:00:00      44.0       2.0
2018-01-04 14:00:00       NaN       NaN
2018-01-04 15:00:00       NaN       NaN
```